# Console Blanking on Dietpi with Waveshare LCD

Tags: raspberry-pi, console

I am having trouble with my screen blanking. I am using a waveshare 1.3 inch lcd screen on a raspberry pi running dietpi 7.8.2. No matter what I try, the screen blanks after 60 seconds with no input. In fact, the backlight turns off as well. I can wake the screen up with some types of input. ctrl+c and enter seem to work. I have tried several things to turn off this behavior, but I cannot seem to get the screen to stay on.

Here are some details on things I have tried and my settings:

```
cat /sys/module/kernel/parameters/consoleblank
0
```

Some settings from my /boot/config.txt

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_cvt=300 300 60 1 0 0 0
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
display_rotate=0
consoleblank=0
```

I have tried setterm --blank 0 and setterm --powerdown 0 as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have a dietpi on a normal monitor or over ssh. I can come up with 4 solutions, listed below in order of likelihood to solve the problem:

1. `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/power/`  explained at the end (most likley)
2. `dietpi-config`   (I guess you already did that command.)
3. The screens **ribbon/cable/piggyback or gpio connector to the screen connections are lose** and when it warms up or is moved, it blanks out. The engineers trick is to squeeze the joint to see if it comes back intermittently, or re-solder "dry solder" joints **or the best trick** is if the ribbon is clip-in to use a  graphite 2B or softer 0.3mm engineering pencil to draw back each and every ribbon contact; it works like magic.

   Obviously graphite is conductive so do not draw randomly and do not drop bits on boards! **Do it when powered off**.
4. **Waveshare**: some screens have been discontinued and are "pants". However waveshare in general is very good quality.

I found this directory which may help:

```
cd /sys/class/backlight
```

Under there are a number of directories and files specifically in my case
(that may differ from yours):

```
$ cd /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0
dietpi@pihole:/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0$
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 May 16 14:33 uevent
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 May 16 14:33 subsystem -> ../../../../../class/backlight/
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 May 16 14:33 type
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 May 16 14:33 max_brightness
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 May 16 14:33 brightness
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 May 17 09:50 power/   # <<< THIS DIRECTORY!
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 May 20 20:17 scale
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 May 20 20:17 device -> ../../../0000:00:01.0/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 May 20 20:17 bl_power
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 May 20 20:17 actual_brightness
```

I found the file in the directory `power/`  to be of most interest and entries in there to be set mostly to just one line:

```
0
```

**Zero 0** in timings usually means either OFF or it means run forever without a timeout.  I am guessing one of those files has **60** in it!

In addition I found another user using the `xset` command but the dietpi did not have that.